# Create a main window like desktop of windows

Tags: wpf, xaml

I was wondering if I can create a main Window including icons for opening sub windows, and as  I maximize the sub window , the sub window just snaps to the container which is defined in the main form as the area of sub windows (the sub window shouldn't take the whole screen , it just snaps to predefined container (sub windows should seem something like `fire fox` tabs))
I hope I could get my purpose.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may start from [WPF Multiple Document Interface (MDI)](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/).